# How to solve initial very slow EF Entity call which uses TPH and Complex Types?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using EF6

I have a generic table which holds data for different types of class objects using the "Table Per Hierarchy" Approach. In addition these class objects use complex types for defining types for their properties.

So using a made up example,

Table = Person

"Mike the Teacher" is a "Teacher" instance of Person with a personType of "Teacher"

The  "Teacher" instance has 2 properties, complextypePersonalDetails and complextypeAddress.

complextypePersonalDetails contains
     First Name, Surname and Age.

complextypeAddress contains
     HouseName, Street, Town, City, County.

I admit that this design may be over the top, and the problem may be of my making, but that aside I wanted to check to see whether I could do anymore with EF6 before I rewrite it.

I am performance profiling the code with JetBrains DotTrace.

On first call, say on
       personTeacher = db.person.OfType().First()

I get a massive delay of around 150,000ms

around:

```
     SerializedGeneratedViewOfType (150,000ms)
          TryGenerateQueryViewOfType
               GenerateTypeSpecificQueryView
                    GenerateQueryViewForSingleExtent
                        GenerateQueryViewForExtentAndType
                           GenerateViewsForExtentAndType
                              GenerateViewComponents
                                 EnsureExtentIsFullyMapped (90,000ms)
                                 GenerateCaseStatements    (60,000ms)
```

I have created a pregenerated View using the "InteractivePreGeneratedViews" nuget package which creates the SQL. However even with this I still need to incur my first hit. Also this hit seems to happen every time the Webserver/Website/AppPool is restarted.

I am not totally sure of the EF process, but I guess there is some further form of runtime compilation or caching which happens when web app starts. Where could this be happening and is there a proactive method that I could use to pregenerate/precompile/precache this problem away.

In the medium term, we will rewrite this code in Dapper or EF.Core. So for now, any thoughts on what can be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had commented on this before, but retracted it, but just agreeing with "this design may be over the top, and the problem may be of my making", but I thought I'd see if anyone else jumped in.

The initial spin-up cost is due to EF needing to resolve the mapping for your schema. This happens once, the first time a DBSet on the context is accessed. You can mitigate this by executing a query on your application start, I.e.

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Initialization stuff...

  using (var context = new MyContext())
  {
     var result = context.MyTable.Any(); // Spin up will happen here, not when the first user attempts to access a query.
  }
}
```

You actually need to run a query for the the DbContext to resolve the mapping, just new-ing one up won't do it.

For larger, or more complex schemas you can also look to utilize bounded contexts where each context maps a particular set of relationships for a specific area of the application. The less complex/comprehensive a context is, the faster it initializes.

As far as the design goes, TPH is for representing inheritance, which is where you need to establish an "is-a" relation between like entities. Relational models, and ORMs by definition can support this, but they're geared more towards "has-a" relationships. Rather than having a model where you go "is-a person with an address", the relation is best mapped out that a person may "have-an" address. I've worked on a system that was designed by a team of engineers where an entire reporting system with dynamic rules was represented by 6 tables. Honestly, those designs are a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for this. Good Advice. I do run  "Context.person.OfType<Teacher>().Any(); " as part of a Startup Controller Action that I wrote to manually warmup the code. I could put it in Application_Start but with 10 different entities of this type to warm up, Application_Startup may take a while.

Comment: It's only a cost per DbContext, not per entity. When the DbContext is first used, it needs to resolve the mappings, all mappings for the context, not just the entities queried. This is effectively a static operation, hence the 1-off cost so new context instances being spun up don't get hit with this mapping until the Application Pool is cycled. If you have 10 different DbContext classes and each has a significant spin-up, then yeah, there would be a delay on restarting the website. The next thing to check is IIS to ensure the app pool is set to "AlwaysRunning" for intermittently used sites.

Comment: There's a specific performance issue when generating the queries when OfType() is used, which persists after the DbContext has been warmed up, so I don't think this answer is applicable to the question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are getting at with the comment and down-vote. The issue was around the first-run cost of a query after an app pool cycles. That is the DbContext static initialization which you can avoid happening by running a simple, fast query on start up so that this cost doesn't occur during a first user operation on the site. I did not suggest using "OfType", that was just his example. My comment was that the warm-up doesn't need to be done for every entity, just one to resolve the mapping for the DbContext.

Comment: Also, in normal use of inheritance you wouldn't bother with a `DbSet<Person>` in a DbContext, you would have `DbSet<Teacher>` vs. `DbSet<Student>`, etc. negating the need to do any casting/OfType. Casting would only be needed when dealing with relationships to a Person that could be either Teacher or Student.

Comment: The downvote is to indicate that I don't think your answer is applicable to the question. This is not a problem of DbContext initialization. There's a specific performance penalty when OfType() is used.

Comment: His question was around the "First hit" cost, which is the static DbContext initialization. He wasn't immediately concerned with the cost of every OfType() query, but the first query cost after an app pool cycles which is what my answer focused on. OfType() costs are incurred with *every* such query, which is a different matter than what the OP raised.

Comment: No, OfType() has a distinct performance penalty on its first call, after the DbContext has been warmed up. The performance penalty is gone on subsequent enumerations of the same query. Note the question includes an excerpt from DotTrace that shows where OP thinks most of the slowdown is occurring (SerializedGeneratedViewOfType).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why OfType() is so slow, but I found a fast and easy workaround by replacing it with a cast; EntityFramework seems to support that just fine and without the performance penalty.

```
var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{
    // warn up
    Console.WriteLine(db.People.Count());
    Console.WriteLine($"{stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");

    // fast
    Console.WriteLine(db.People.Select(p => p as Teacher).Where(p => p != null).Count());
    Console.WriteLine($"{stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");

    // slow
    Console.WriteLine(db.People.OfType<Teacher>().Count());
    Console.WriteLine($"{stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
}
```

```
20
3308 ms
2
3796 ms
2
10026 ms
```

Comment: Or Just `db.People.Where(x => x.Discriminator == "Teacher").Count()` which should be in the 10's to 100 ms. Where Discriminator should be an indexed column in the TPH schema. (Ideally an enum/int, used a string for a readable example) Where inheritance is used, references and DbSets should be using the sub-type wherever possible rather than the base type so casting is used only as absolutely necessary.

Comment: I used Count() to keep my example minimal, but in reality we'd want to use the result of the cast in further LINQ methods.